# using jquery with database

Tags: jquery

can some one give me some perfect example or point me to the blog or forum where I can find jquery link with database. That is jquery doing some manuplation on the values from the database ? especially checkboxes and radio button

I only want the example linking client side and server side interaction using jquery

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. jQuery is a javascript framework suitable for manipulating the DOM and performing AJAX queries. It has absolutely nothing to do with a database.

Comment: sorry I mean jquery link with asp.net. like base on the value retrieve  from database a whole div is hidden or not hidden using jquery

Comment: Aha, you might wan't to edit your above question to mention that. You could use jQuery for manipulating the client-side database which is a whole different beast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read up on the concepts behind AJAX. Getting a value from a database has nothing to do with JS.

One approach is to use ASP.NET WebMethods and a ScriptManager to link your codebehind (Where you have DB access) to your JS on the client side.

http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/Call-WebMethod-from-Javascript-in-ASPNET.aspx

This way your javascript calls a method in your codebehind that looks up the value and returns it to your javascript which will then use jQuery to show/hide a div for you.

Javascript (ask for show/hide status) -> Webmethod (ASP.NET DB Lookup) -> Javascript (show hide with jquery based on result)

Answer (score 2):

Javascript has nothing to do with DBs. It, on the other hand, can interact with server side scripts (trough AJAX) that can interact with DBs.

Check out the `jQuery.ajax()` method here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/